# Fluent bindings broken in v3.5?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Since upgrading to MvvmCross v3.5 we've found that all our bindings like the following have broken.

```
set.Bind(this).For("ManualSync").To(vm => vm.ManualSync).OneWay();
```

They work if we change them to

```
set.Bind(this).For(t => t.ManualSync).To(vm => vm.ManualSync).OneWay();
```

Is this a bug or to be expected? One issue with the second style of binding is that you have to have a get accessor, whilst you don't with the first style.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "broken" mean? Does it mean you see an exception? Does it mean you see trace? At runtime, the `expression` format of the bindings is evaluated to create the `string` format... so if the `expression` format works the `string` format should to. The only caveat I know to that is when the Xamarin Android linker strips out properties...

Comment: Broken, as in it doesn't work. i.e. the bound method is never called. 
If I use the first binding type (the string) and add a get accessor it works. If I remove the get accessor it stops working.
I hadn't noticed before but I'm seeing this

`MvxBind:Warning:  8.32 Failed to create target binding for binding BlurImage for BlurImage`

It looks like the linker is stripping the method out but adding an Include method to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs doesn't fix it. Any thoughts?